# storing a cell reference in a variable and accessing that cell's value

Tags: excel, vba

i'm trying to get the value of one cell in a column (column B). this cell is in the same row as the last cell which has a value in another (column A)

```
maxrowina = ws.Range("A1").Offset(ws.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
maxcellinb = "B" & str(maxrowina)
MsgBox (ws.Range(dbhobcell).Value)
```

but i keep on getting a runtime error: 91.
how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things :)

1) You don't need **str(maxrowina)**. You can use this

```
maxcellinb = "B" & maxrowina
```

2) Shouldn't **MsgBox (ws.Range(dbhobcell).Value)** be

```
MsgBox (ws.Range(maxcellinb).Value)
```

**Complete Code**

```
maxrowina = ws.Range("A1").Offset(ws.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
maxcellinb = "B" & maxrowina
MsgBox (ws.Range(maxcellinb).Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little tighter on the MaxRow code:

```
MaxRowInA = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox ws.Range("B" & MaxRowInA).Value
```

Tigher still:

```
MsgBox ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(,1).Value
```